# Web Apps Meta > Users > Voters isn't working

Tags: support, status-bydesign, statistics, voting

The tabs week, month, quarter and year of Web Apps Meta > Users > Voters shows blank

[image: Voters > Year]

but the similar page on other sites works fine.

[image: Votantes > Año]

Comment: I feel like there's a duplicate of this question somewhere.  I think there's a threshold of 5 votes, otherwise a user doesn't show up in the list.  Since we're not that far into the month/quarter/year, this is (unfortunately) not surprising based on the traffic Meta gets.

Comment: I think that I already made five votes this year.

Comment: Duplicate was deleted: https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/has-the-system-lost-its-marbles-part-ii (10K only) but from [SU]'s meta we ascertained it was probably 10 votes, not 5.

Comment: @pnuts : replaced [tag:bug] by [tag:support]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that the threshold is 10 votes, as jonsca mentioned in a comment to the question.

[image]